# Use of the word "petrol" as a solvent in British English?

Tags: terminology, british-english, technical

In the clip below from YouTube, the narrator refers to the can of liquid solvent shown below as "petrol":

[image]

However, this container looks like the type we use in America to store what is commonly known as "lighter fluid," and is actually naptha. Naptha can be used as a solvent. Is the practice in Britain to refer to naptha (or other organic solvents) as "petrol" or does the word in this use mean something else?

Comment: As a former chemist, residing in the UK all my life, I would not - and I do not know anyone who would - call the above 'petrol'. 'Petrol' is a mixture of hydrocarbons of specific chain lengths. The above is probably kerosene, which is a cruder distillate of petroleum. Both petrol and kerosene may be used as solvents depending on what is being dissolved.

Comment: @NigelJ: Some Brits must refer to lighter fluid as petrol. Otherwise, do you have an explanation for : https://www.amazon.co.uk/Zippo-Lighter-Fluid-Petrol-Flints/dp/B003811N7W

Comment: @KarlG ' The world famous ZIPPO trademark is registered on the Principal Register _in the United States_ ' says their website. It's an American Company and an American Product. And if it is genuinely petrol then it shouldn't be. It ought to have a lower flash point if it is to be used domestically as lighter fluid.

Comment: @NigelJ: Yes, Zippo is an American brand, but it's not being flogged on UK eBay by the manufacturer. eBay merchants will put synonyms in titles to facilitate hits in a search. My reasoning is that if there are others besides the guy in the youtube video who call it "petrol," then that's why it's searchable on Amazon.

Comment: @KarlG As they say in the House of Commons 'I refer the Honourable Member to my answer to the previous question'.